# How to plot frequency spectrum of acoustic signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to plot a frequency spectrum of my signal, and I realize when I plot the power in the frequency domain is over 12e11, is that correct?  If not,  what is the correct interval of the power of the signal in my case? I'm working on an acoustic signal implemented on a smartphone. And I want to make sure my code is correct.

```matlab
%spectrum analysis of the signal
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
fs = 48000;%sample rate
x = fopen('F:\fastICATest\1.pcm');%original sound signal
y  = fread(x, inf, 'int16');
figure
plot(y)
xlabel('sample number')
ylabel('amplitude')
figure
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
spe = spectrogram(y, 512,0,512, fs, 'yaxis');% read the spectrogram of the signal with peak
plot(abs(spe))
figure
spectrogram(y, 512,0,512,fs,'yaxis');%read the spectrogram of the signal
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
signal_short = y(14.48e5:15.2e5);
t = 1/fs:length(signal_short) - 1/fs;%time domain
figure
plot(t,signal_short)
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('amplitude')
xlim([0 t(end)])
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
m = length(signal_short);
n = pow2(nextpow2(m));
z = fft(signal_short,n);% applying the fft to spectrum
zz = fftshift(z)% frequency shift of fft
figure
plot(abs(z))
xlabel('Frequency')
figure
plot(abs(zz))
xlabel('Frequency shift')
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% f = (0:n-1)*(fs/n);
f = -fs/n:fs/n:fs/2-fs/n;%requency specification
power = abs(zz).^2/n; %power of the signal
figure
plot(f(1:floor(n/2)), power(1:floor(n/2)))
xlabel('Frequency')
ylabel('Power')
```

Comment: Your input is 16-bit ints. When squared you get quite large values. But the input is in arbitrary units, and so your power is in arbitrary units as well. The only thing you can do is compare the power in different sections of your signal, or compare the power in different frequency bands. The actual values are useless beyond that.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I separated the signal by sequences as u requested, and I realize that the power of the signal at different sections change. So can I conclude when the signal power is high the signal is good? and when is low the signal is weak?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You can compare power computed this way across signals recorded in the same way.